# Couldn't figure out where to add this class into the html for .net mvc

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have this in c# mvc

```
    <label class="control-label">Allow Save Password <span class="text-danger">*</span></label>
    @Html.DropDownListFor( m => m.AllowSavePassword, 
   new List<SelectListItem>{ new SelectListItem{Text="Yes", Value="True",Selected=true},new SelectListItem{Text="No", Value="False"}}, 
   "Select One")
```

wanted to add in a class into it
the class is `new { @class = "form-style" }`

any clue add in at which part to not throwing error?

Answer (score 0):

This will be a part of your view, such as Index.csthml.  With all due respect, I would suggest reviewing ASP.NET Core MVC training videos from YouTube.  There are several good ones that help explain the basics.